# Fragment not showing up and breaks other buttons on Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm learning how to use Fragments, and trying to add a fragment `tag_button.xml` at runtime to a FrameLayout `tagFragmentContainer` deep within another layout, `deepLayout.xml`. The app now crashes with the error: "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" on the last line mentioned in `deepLayoutActivity`, within a case statement.

`tagFragmentContainer`, within a LinearLayout in the middle of a large layout file, `deepLayout.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/tagButtonsLayout"
  android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
  android:visibility="gone"
  style="@style/Form">
    <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/tagFragmentContainer"
       android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
       style="@style/Form">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In `deepLayoutActivity`, when a certain option in the layout is selected, I make visible `tagButtonsLayout` and add a `TagButtonFragment`. I need to be able to do this several times:

```
final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tagButtonsLayout);
lm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
TagButtonFragment firstFragment = new TagButtonFragment();

// Add the fragment to the 'tagFragmentContainer' FrameLayout
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.tagFragmentContainer, firstFragment, "tagOne").commit();
```

`TagButtonActivity` **is no longer used**:

```
public class TagButtonActivity extends FragmentActivity
{

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.deepLayout);

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
         return;

    TagButtonFragment firstFragment = new TagButtonFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.tagFragmentContainer, 
                                firstFragment, "tagOne").commit();
  }
}
```

`TagButtonFragment`:

```
public class TagButtonFragment extends Fragment
{
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
                            savedInstanceState)
   {
      // Inflate the layout for this fragment
      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_button, container, false);
   }
}
```

`tag_button.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  style="@style/Form">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tag_button_header"
    style="@style/FieldHeader"
    android:text="example text"/>
    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/tag_button_block"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
      android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
      android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
      android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
      android:layout_height="43dip"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:background="@drawable/row_spinner_selector">

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/question_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tag_question_text"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/question_arrow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="@string/not_selected"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would certainly appreciate any help in figuring this out from someone who knows fragments better than me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all when you want to create a Fragment by XML, you put it either inside the View container or you do it by code (like you did with `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.tagFragmentContainer, firstFragment, "tagOne").commit();`)

Next is, you're inflating a layout with a Fragment, that's inflating a layout with another Fragment, that's inflating a layout with another Fragment, etc. and each of these layouts are empty (you see the problem?). Note that the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`namespace is only used for the Graphical Layout Viewer, it's not used for inflating layouts in your Fragments and thus `tools:layout="@layout/tag_button"` does nothing except displaying the layout inside the Graphical Layout Viewer, not really inflating anything.

So the correct way of inflating your layout would be:

```
public class TagButtonFragment extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // Inflate the layout for this fragment
      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_button, container, false);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured since tab_button wasn't empty, inflating fragment_tag_button which included tag_button would work. Is that wrong then? When I inflated R.layout.tag_button in instead of fragment_tab_button, it's no longer in an infinite loop, but it doesn't show the button tag_button contains.

Comment: It also totally killed the remaining buttons in the original layout. These fragments aren't quite clicking just yet.

Comment: When inflating, it says the container is the FrameLayout id tagFragmentContainer. Is that right? It is the parent FrameLayout.

Comment: Post your Layout `tag_button.xml`, so I can inspect what can be wrong wih your buttons. But the rest is spot on. When you're doing `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.tagFragmentContainer, firstFragment, "tagOne").commit();` the container with the ID `R.id.tagFragmentContainer` will be the parent container of your Fragment.

Comment: Thank you! tag_button.xml has been added.

Comment: Well it seems to me that you're throwing away your deepLayout by starting a new Activity TagButtonActivity, which has itself a new layout action_expense.xml. If this new layout does not have an Id R.id.tagFragmentContainer, there is no way your fragment can be added into layout.

Comment: please clarify if you really want to start a new activity, although your old activity has the layout id you need to add your fragment

Comment: I need to keep my deepLayout. I only started a new activity because that's what I thought was the correct thing to do. What's the best way to just add the new fragment and subsequent fragments to the deepLayout? I am setting currently deepLayout as the view in TagButtonActivity. Should I do it differently?

Comment: Well it seems you haven't understood the concept of Fragments. Did you read the Fragments guide? http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html The Android developers guide is the first address to search for how to do things. ;-) But still, to make it quick: You don't need a new Activity to add a Fragment. The FragmentManager is available for EVERY Activity. FragmentActivity is only needed, if you need to use the compatibility library

Comment: Makes sense. I did read the Fragments guide. It has an example that makes a new Activity, but I obviously missed some things. I bypassed my TagButtonActivity and instead of calling `startActivity()` on it, I moved `TagButtonFragment firstFragment = new TagButtonFragment();` and `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.tagFragmentContainer, firstFragment, "tagOne").commit();` there instead, but now I get the following exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState` when the app crashes. No luck fixing it yet. Suggestions?

Comment: I'm backwards compatible to API 8 so I do need to use the compatibility library. I had my `deepLayout` Activity's parent class extend `FragmentActivity` so I could use `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: It seems you're finishing your deepLayoutActivity and then committing your Fragment. Please post your code.

Comment: The code is updated with the latest. As far as I know, I'm not finishing deepLayoutActivity at all, just committing my Fragment before the `case` statement breaks.

Comment: There's nothing to show. All the code involved in deepLayout is in a case statement that is triggered when a category is chosen from a spinner.

Comment: Well without knowing the full context of your problem (i.e. your code), I can't really pull out the problem of thin air. Your provided Exception information seems to come from a wrong assumption of how to use Fragments inside an Activity. Read this, it might help you: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

Comment: In general, when using Fragments: Don't ever hold any references to your Activity or any other Context related component, if you're not 100% sure what you are doing. When in doubt, ALWAYS use the getter methods provided by the Android API. Everything is managed by Android, so be careful, when you try to manage stuff on your own. Only hook into the callback mechanisms provided by Android and do your stuff there, don't do it on your own.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that website. It had the answer I was needed. I have to `commitAllowingStateLoss()` because nothing is added until a Category is picked that may or may not have the right info.